# Detect Circle Using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a gray scale Image. I want to detect the inner circle marked with redline (with paint) and then crop that region from the original image.

[image]

I followed the below steps:

```
I= imread('myimage');
bw = im2bw(I,graythresh(I));

bw = bwareaopen(bw,900);
[~, threshold] = edge(bw, 'sobel');
 fudgeFactor = .5;
im = edge(bw,'sobel', threshold * fudgeFactor);
[c,r] = imfindcircles(im,[1,20]);
viscircles(c,r);
```

Problem is using `imfindcircles` detects small circles instead of selecting my single circle.  I also can not use `circle_hough` function as it is not in my  MATLAB (saw an example in stackoverflow). So how can i detect my marked circle in the image and crop the region inside it from the original Image `I`?

Comment: Surely the radius of that circle is larger than the `[1,20]` range you give it.

Comment: @beaker,
I tried with [5,500] but no luck. I hope I am not using in wrong way.

Comment: @beaker Detects small noises around the inner circle not the acutal circle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that any and all images you will use for this purpose will yield similar edges (2 cleanly separated circles), you can do the following:

1) Use `imclose` with a small disk to close out any possible small discontinuities during edge detection.

2) Use `bwconncomp` to find the 2 circles. The output struct of `bwconncomp` should have 2 elements, 1 corresponding to the outer circle, the other the inner.

3) Search the pixelIDXlist of both elements, find the minimum x coordinate of both elements. The element with the bigger minimum is your inner circle.

Comment: Yes for all the images I will get similar edges.

Comment: I got the inner circle and erased the big circle using below code:
<code>
numPixels = cellfun(@numel,cc.PixelIdxList);
[biggest,idx] = min(numPixels);
im(cc.PixelIdxList{idx}) = 0;
subplot(2,2,4), imshow(im), title('Inner Cirlces Only');
</code>
Now How can I cut this inncer circle area from the original image?

Comment: Use `BW2= imfill(BW,'holes')` to fill the circle, the grab the calues using `image(filledholecircle == 1);`

Comment: What do you mean by "filledholecircle " is it "BW2" or any matlab function? And what did you meant by "calues"? Could you explain please?

Comment: I was lazy, BW is your circle edge:
`BW2= imfill(BW,'holes')`
`Result = zeros(size(BW));`
`Result(BW2==1) = YourOriginalImage(BW2==1);`

Comment: I got the circle. There is only one circle in the image. Now I want to crop the circle area from the original Image 'I'.  What shouldl I do?